# User Data Script Completion

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am working on an automation and passing some script to `user data` while creating the EC2 Instances.
I am using boto3 (python) for my automation.

The script that I am passing to `user data` take nearly 30 minutes to complete and based on that I have to pull the logs and do some stuff on that.

to pull the data when the script is completed, I should be knowing the when is it completing. is there some way to know if the script in user data is completed and if then pull the logs generated.

I have tried waiter in boto3

```
class EC2.Waiter.InstanceStatusOk
waiter = client.get_waiter('instance_status_ok')
wait(**kwargs)
Polls EC2.Client.describe_instance_status() every 15 seconds until a successful state is reached. An error is returned after 40 failed checks.

See also: AWS API Documentation

Request Syntax

waiter.wait(
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'string',
            'Values': [
                'string',
            ]
        },
    ],
    InstanceIds=[
        'string',
    ],
    MaxResults=123,
    NextToken='string',
    DryRun=True|False,
    IncludeAllInstances=True|False,
    WaiterConfig={
        'Delay': 123,
        'MaxAttempts': 123
    }
)
```

[get_waiter](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.get_waiter)

This seems to be checking the status from `EC2.Client.describe_instance_status()` but what if my script takes longer to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Boto3 can't detect when the script completes. There is nothing in the AWS API that can tell you when the script completed, because only the operating system on the EC2 server knows when the script actually completes. What you need to do is add an action to the end of the script to send a notification somewhere like an SNS topic, or add a task to an SQS queue, and use that as your trigger for the next set of actions you need to perform.